# How do I configure a Debian webserver for push Git repo on it?

Tags: php, linux, git, server

I am working in a PHP developer team and I have Debian Linux web server in my local area network and installed LAMP on it.

So everything was OK until we are planned to using Git as a version control system and use it in our team work. Our scenario is when somebody push Git repository to Linux server, the website that is hosted on it takes effects and everyone in our LAN network can access to it like this:

```
192.168.1.100/mysite
```

Every thing is OK, we can pull from server and also push to it!
But the problem is when we access the website on the server the `mysite` folder in `/var/www` didn't take effect.

I've searched the internet and find that we should have a bare repository that connected to a master repository.  But I'm new to Git , so I don't know how to do it.

***Edited:***
If possible tell me how to do this on GUI, I have SourceTree.Anything else is OK.

Comment: Are you pulling the changesets?

Comment: are you pulling the repo??

Comment: yes I pull it from server.

Answer (score 2):

If you are launching your project first time on the server, then you have to clone it first. suppose i am trying to launch [this](https://github.com/Eaiman/BitmapHandler) repo from my github account. then i have to do this:

1. go to your directory. for you this is: `/var/www`
2. run this commant: `sudo git clone
   https://github.com/Eaiman/BitmapHandler.git`

if console is saying something like `git` is not a command or anything like this, then you have to install it first.

Install git:
run this command: `sudo apt-get install git`

You are done. your project will be pulled to your `/va/www/` directory.

After that,

1. when you made any change in your project. first push the changes to
   git from your local PC.
2. then login to your server
3. go to `/var/www/` directory
4. run this command: `sudo git pull origin master`. `master` is the branch
   name. use the branch you want to pull from. suppose i have two
   branch. 1. master 2. dev-shoshi. then i can run this: `sudo git pull
   origin master` or this: `sudo git pull origin dev-shoshi` command

hope it will help. let me know if have any question.

Comment: Thank you, Shoshi.
I will tell you what I have done hope it makes sense for you.
I install LAMP on my LAN server.
I copy my website to /var/www/mywebsite .
Then I install Git.
I do the command : "git init" in "mywebsite" folder.
Then I do : "git add ." 
And then I do: "git commit "mycommit" ".
Then I install SourceTree GUI on my computer and connect to my repository with ssh.
Then I clone the repository with my SourceTree GUI on my client.
All other people in my team do last step too.
Everybody work on the master branch in own computer and push it to my LAN server.

Comment: Now I want to if somebody in my network see my site : 192.168.1.100/mysite.
He can see last changes I made in repository in my website.
How can i do that automatically?Or if manually possible?